Thriller where identical twin sister makes boyfriend believe she is his girlfriend?
It is a thriller film released sometime between 2009-2012 where a boyfriend and girlfriend are living together (in LA I think - she might be an aspiring actress) and the girlfriend goes away and her identical twin sister comes to stay and the boyfriend thinks it is his girlfriend? In the end I think he kills the twin and then his real girlfriend comes home unaware. It was a low budget film. 

Sounds like Engagement from 2012.

Henry has just learned that his fiancée Carolyn has a twin sister, Laura. While Carolyn leaves town for a few weeks, Laura temporarily moves in to Henry and Carolyn's apartment. Upon Laura's arrival, Henry suspects that Carolyn is testing his fidelity by playing the role of her imaginary twin sister. He immediately starts searching for clues to solve this haunting mystery. Soon, Laura's mind games prove too much for Henry, who can't help but be seduced all over again.

He ends up killing her, but I think the ending's a bit ambivalent. Here's the trailer:



